# What would you call an organization to which a certificate is issued?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, terminology, technology

Let’s say I am writing some code that inspects the SSL Certificate issued to some website. There is the *issuer* which can be, for example, Verisign. What would you call the organization to which the certificate is issued? I am looking for a 1-2 word name, such as "*Issue-ee*" or similar. Essentially I am looking for a way to say “The organization to which the certificate was issued”.

Comment: I would have thought "the subject" or the "certification subject" would be good terms to use.

Answer (score 1):

The word **[recipient](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/recipient)** is often used to indicate the entity to whom an award or certificate is presented or issued.

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/recipient)

> noun
> a person or thing that receives; receiver:
> *the recipient of a prize.*

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use: "Issued To".

Example

> Issued To: Acme Bricks, Inc.